# Añadir us string a un objecto con el operador +=

Tags: javascript

Tengo un objeto, y un contador:

```
  let dataProductores = {};
  let count = 0;
```

donde quiero ir añadiendo en cada posición del objeto varios string de la siguiente manera:

```
  dataProductores[count] += `${ele},`;
```

el resultado de:

```
  console.log(JSON.stringify(dataProductores));
```

es:

```
{
 "0":"undefinedstring, string, string",
 "2":"undefinedstring, string, string
}
```

No se porque en el inicio de cada posición me da undefined, cuando el string que inserto siempre tiene un valor válido.

Comment: No necesitas un arreglo para realizar eso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar un array y agregar objetos con su valores de element

```js
let dataProductores = [] // array para guardar datos

let count = 0;

dataProductores[count] = { name: 'string 1' };

count++;

dataProductores[count] = { name: 'string 1' };


console.log(JSON.stringify(dataProductores))
```

Otra opcion es esta:

```js
let dataProductores = {} // objeto para guardar datos

let count = 0;
// si el valor en count es undefined agrega si no concatena
dataProductores[count ] = dataProductores[count] === undefined ? 'str,' :  dataProductores[count] += 'str,'

count++;

dataProductores[count ] = dataProductores[count] === undefined ? 'str,' :  dataProductores[count] += 'str,'


console.log(JSON.stringify(dataProductores))
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que primero tendrías que declarar un primer valor en esa posición del objeto (puede ser vacío).

```
dataProductores[count] = "string1";
```

Luego puedes agregar más cadenas al objeto en la misma posición con tu código.